# perl regex replace increase numeric value from match in-place

Tags: perl

Is there a way to regex replace a value by the increased +1 or +2 value in Perl in one regex operation? E.g. something that changes L001 to L002 or L003 or L004 below:

```
$ echo XYZ123-123-123x_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz | perl -lne '$_ =~ /\_L(\d{3})/; $new=sprintf("%03d",$1+1); s/\_L\d{3}/\_L$new/;print'

XYZ123-123-123x_S6_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

But doing it in-place in the regex operation, similar to below (which does not work):

```
echo XYZ123-123-123x_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz | perl -lne 's/\_L(\d{3})/\_$1+1/;print'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `/e` on the regex, to specify 'evaluate'.

But if you're doing that, you're doing a evaluation, so you can't just use barewords any more. `\_1+1` isn't valid perl. You could do `$1+1` but that'll only give you `2` not `002`.

So you also need `sprintf` to zero pad.

And whilst you're at it, instead of the trailing print, you can use `-p` instead of `-n`.

And get:

```
echo XYZ123-123-123x_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz | perl -pe 's/_L(\d{3})/sprintf("_L%03d",$1+1)/e'
```

Which gives you:

```
XYZ123-123-123x_S6_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
```